# mysql Dealing with variable key that can change

Tags: mysql, database, variables, foreign-keys, key

I ran into a problem. I store 3 values. The UUID of a player, the name of the player and the amount of coins of each player. Every player can change their name when they are offline. However, if a player comes back, I have to register the NEW name of the player, keep the UUID and most important, keep the value of coins.

I have tried multiple things like:

```
INSERT INTO playerdata (uuid, player) VALUES('EXAMPLE', ‘A') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE player=VALUES(player);
```

However, this doesn't work out when player B changes his name to the old name of player A (that never went back online), because Player B has now inherited that 10 coins of player A.

```
REPLACE INTO playerdata (uuid, player) VALUES(?, ?);
```

This also doesn't work out, because the player Auto incrementID is *****, and when it updates (even with the same player), you automatically have 0 coins, no matter what.

I'm stuck. As I must register the UUID with the player name. I can't live with only the UUID, because in-game, To lookup every UUID of each player through a other method is not very fast.

Simplified version of the DB:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS playerdata(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  uuid VARCHAR(36) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  player VARCHAR(16) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  coins INT DEFAULT 0)
```

Comment: Don't bother with the `uuid`. Use `id` and use `UPDATE` statements. They are surprisingly effective at updating data... In other words, you're trying to remove and recreate the record when the name changes. Don't. Update the existing record with the new name.

Comment: From the information you've provided, it does not appear there is even a key to trigger "ON DUPLICATE KEY".